# Carbon-fields does't show maked fields

Tags: wordpress, carbon-fields

I create container for theme options and add fields array to it. Then open this options page, see the title and empty block where the fields should be add. How to display fields?

Carbon Fields 2.1.0

```
use Carbon_Fields\Container;
use Carbon_Fields\Field;
Container::make( 'theme_options', __( 'Theme Options', 'crb' ) )
  ->add_fields( array(
      Field::make( 'text', 'crb_text', 'Text Field' ),
  ) );
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 5):

In order to get Carbon Fields to work in a Plugin, I had to define the value of `Carbon_Fields\URL` to fix it.

My bootstrap code at the root file of my plugin looks like so:

```php
// Define the url where Carbon Fields assets will be enqueued from
define( 'Carbon_Fields\URL', trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) . 'vendor/htmlburger/carbon-fields/' );

// Boot Carbon Fields
\Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();

// Return the class that sets up the settings pages
return new \MyPlugin\Settings();
```

You can see all the Carbon Field constants that are possible to override before bootstrap here: https://github.com/htmlburger/carbon-fields/blob/development/config.php

Comment: The `Carbon_Fields\URL` works for me. 
Note that we need to point the correct url to `your_plugin_url/vendor/htmlburger/carbon-fields/`

Comment: Great, after 4 hours of thinking it was me doing it wrong it's been fixed! this should be in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code on functions.php and Use this code in below,

```html
use Carbon_Fields\Field;
use Carbon_Fields\Container;

add_action( 'carbon_fields_register_fields', 'crb_attach_theme_options' );
function crb_attach_theme_options() {
    Container::make( 'theme_options', __( 'Theme Options', 'crb' ) )
        ->add_fields( array(
            Field::make( 'rich_text', 'crb_footer_copyright', 'Copyright' ),
        ) );
}
```

Comment: I moved the function to a separate file.

Comment: add_action( 'carbon_fields_register_fields', 'estore_register_custom_fields' );    
function estore_register_custom_fields() {  
 require get_template_directory() . '/includes/custom-fields-options/theme-options.php';  
}`

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, and this does not solve the problem.  For post_meta containers, the metabox appears but it's always empty.